# hostapd driver error with AR9271 Chipset

Tags: networking, drivers, raspberrypi

I am trying to install `hostapd` on my raspberry pi with a `TP-Link TL-WN722N` Wireless USB stick.
in the `/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf` file, I entered `driver=nl80211`.
when I use `sudo /usr/sbin/hostapd /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf` I get the error:
`invalid/unknown driver 'nl80211'`

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the issue by following this tutorial:
https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/Documentation/hostapd